# Performance of SQL Server, apache and django

Tags: sql-server, django, performance, apache, windows-server-2008

I am running into some performance issues on my server, which runs Windows server 2008, SQL Server 2008, and apache.  This is a purely internal website, and is accessed by a total of about 6 people.  However, those six use it heavily all day.  My issue is that django frequently reports a SQL Server timeout error.  After carefully monitoring the server, I've noticed that whenever a web page is loaded Apache's CPU usage shoots up to 100% for a second or two.  The problem arises when there are several users, each with a few pages loading. AFAICS, there are a few things which could be causing this:

1. My django configuration: I am using Johnny Cache, with a memcached backend, but I am also using `DEBUG = True`.  This is because I am still in development, and it is helpful to see a good error report when one of my 6 users finds a bug.  For reference, django-debug-toolbar (which only runs on my testing environment, not the server) shows that an  average page results in about 100 SQL queries.  Is this normal?
2. Apache/SQL Server configuration: I don't know much about tuning either of these so I have left them both with default settings. Is there anything specific I should do to improve performance?
3. Insufficient resources. My server (which is a VM) has been set up with a single 2.4GHz processor and 4Gb RAM. The RAM usage doesn't get above 3Gb, but the CPU seems to be used fully. Is it simply that I need to allocate more resources?

To summarise my question, can anyone with a bit of experience in this sort of setup give me any advice on which of the above I should focus on to improve performance?